# Getting the distortion transformation from points

Tags: image, math, image-processing, opencv

Is it possible to get a rectangle distortion from few fixed points?

This example will explain better what I mean:

Suppose I've got this image with a rectangle and two points, the two points are recognized in the other image where the image is distorted

[image]

How can I reproduce the distortion knowing the position of the two(or maybe three) previous points??

My purpose is to get the distorted rectangle border. It's not an easy image as the one in the example so I can't just filter colors, I need to find a way to get the distorted image border.

Comment: As stated this problem is under constrained. Your second image could be at least a 'rotation + scale + shear' as well as the shear I think you intended it to be.

Comment: Do you know the mapping between points in the original image and the distorted version as well? Without that (e.g. if it's just some simple feature detector) it will be harder too.

Comment: @awoodland, unfortunately not. That's why it is so hard. You may calculate distance, angle to establish a translation/rotation, but you'll never get the right distorted image. I suppose you need more than two points to do something, but even so it's pretty difficult

Comment: I'll have a think, but I suspect you're going to want to bring in some extra information from the images somehow if you want to always find the one true solution fast

Comment: The images can be anything from a panoramic photo to a movie scene, this is pretty bad because I can't rely on something else to find the scene borders

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe what you're looking for can be described as an affine transform. If you want general transform of a planar surface, you may want perspective transform instead.

You can find the OpenCV implementation [here](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/geometric_image_transformations.html). The relevant functions are cv::getAffineTransform which requires 3 pairs of points or cv::getPerspectiveTransform which requires 4 pairs of points.

Note: if you're using an automatic feature detector/matcher, it would be best to use far more point pairs than the minimum and use a robust outlier rejection algorithm like RANSAC.

Comment: thank you, seems like it's pretty hard to get good results. Also because the transformation I'm looking is produced by two or more transformations

Comment: The number of transforms does not matter, performing 100 affine transforms after each other, can be performed by ONE affine transform.

Answer (score 0):

shift and rotation need - 2 points

Affine tranform need - 3 points

Perspective tranform need - 4 points